# Shopify script — discount on Bulk Purchase for specific tags

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am trying to create a script for 25% off when 15 items tagged ‘outerwear’ are added to the cart.

The script loops through the cart for the quantity stored in items_quantities_total but this does not check that those 15 items in the cart all have the qualifying tag.

```rb
Input.cart.line_items.each_with_index do |line_item, index|

  MIN_QTY_IN_CART_15 = 15
  items_quantities = Input.cart&.line_items&.map { |item| item.quantity }
  items_quantities_total = items_quantities.reduce(0, :+)

  discountCollectionPriceBasis = line_item.line_price_was
  if line_item.variant.compare_at_price
    discountCollectionPriceBasis = line_item.variant.compare_at_price * line_item.quantity
  end

  discountCollectionPrice = discountCollectionPriceBasis * 0.75
  if discountCollectionPrice < line_item.line_price 
    unless line_item.line_price_was < discountCollectionPrice
      if line_item.variant.product.tags.include?('outerwear')
        if items_quantities_total >= MIN_QTY_IN_CART_15
          line_item.change_line_price(discountCollectionPrice, message: "Buy 15 outerwear items and get 25% Off!")
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

An example of the result is it currently works even if have 14 of a product not included in my 'outerwear' discount and only 1 of the intended discount item. It then applies 25% off that one item.

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a problem with that code? An unexpected result? An error?

Comment: Yes, an unexpected result. The code includes items without the qualifying variant tag as part of the 15 minimum for the cart. I am hoping that I can check those 15 items all have the qualifying tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you calculate `items_quantities_total` on all `line_items`, not only on the `"outerwear"` ones.

To fix it, you could adjust the line

```
  items_quantities = Input.cart&.line_items&.map { |item| item.quantity }
```

to filter for `"outerwear"` tag.

Comment: Great, thank you claasz. I had been trying to adjust it within the IF statement to no avail. Very helpful.